# htaccess rewrite real directory path to a different, non-existing url, hiding the real path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to use a directory `___test` like `/___test/subdirectory1/` and have some contents, but never show this path in the url. Instead I would like the url `/demo/subdirectory1` or say, `/demo/subdirectory1/images/image.jpg` to point to `/___test/subdirectory1/images/image.jpg` and the url on the browser to stay like: `/demo/subdirectory1/images/image.jpg`. Actually replacing `___test` with `demo`

What I have tried with various problems although it looks like it works sometimes is:

```
RewriteRule ^demo/subdirectory1(.*) ___test/subdirectory1/$1
```

The above works only on:  `demo/subdirectory1` or  `demo/subdirectory1/` (with existing content example an index.html inside `/___test/subdirectory1/`) but not on  `demo/subdirectory1/somethingmore...` although the content is there in this case as well, unfortunately it shows the real directory path in the url.

Additionally, I am using the following to through 404 to anything starting from `/___test` in the url:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /___test/
RewriteRule ^___test/(.*) - [R=404,L,NC]
```

It works, but when I add this, then the previous goes to 404 too, unfortunately (again).
But most important for me is to make the first part right, even if I never make the second work.

Any help really appreciated.
Thanks.

Edit 1:
I have also tried adding the following inside an `/___test/subdirectory1/.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /___test/subdirectory1
```

no success.

Edit 2:
Although it doesn't work well, the best I came up with so far with the help of Jon Lin is the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/demo/subdirectory1(.*)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/___test/subdirectory1/%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/___test/subdirectory1/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^ /___test/subdirectory1/%1 [L]
```

`/demo/subdirectory1` <- OK

`/demo/subdirectory1/` <- OK

`/demo/subdirectory1/subdirectory2` <- Exposes real path

`/demo/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/` <- OK

`/demo/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/subdirectory3` <- Exposes real path

`/demo/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/subdirectory3/` <- OK

As you can see, whatever is deeper level than `subdirectory1` has problem. I just cannot understand why. Testing this on a clean .htaccess file existing in the root of the site (no other deeper) on a linux apache.

Comment: we seem to have the same issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248674/how-to-write-htaccess-rewrite-for-subdirectories-recursively?noredirect=1#comment23249673_16248674

Answer (score 0):

For the most part you're on the right track, but you may need to add a couple of checks so that the `__test` directory isn't exposed:

```
RewriteEngine On

# prevent mod_dir from redirecting to trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/demo/subdirectory1/(.*[^/])
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/___test/subdirectory1/%1 -d    
RewriteRule ^ /demo/subdirectory1/%1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/demo/subdirectory1$
RewriteRule ^ /demo/subdirectory1/ [L,R=301]


# check if the file actually exists first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/demo/subdirectory1/(.*)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/___test/subdirectory1/%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/___test/subdirectory1/%1 -d

# and rewrite only if the resource exists within ___test
RewriteRule ^ /___test/subdirectory1/%1 [L]
```

Making sure that you've ended rewriting in the current iteration by using `[L]`.

Your 404 rule should work but you should remove the trailing slash so that mod_dir won't try to redirect and expose the `___test` directory:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /___test
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer indeed, I just tried both things you gave me (only the first part, or both), and in both cases, the real path is exposed again. I would like to mention that I use an absolutely clean .htaccess file in clean directories. Only the index.html files are there for testing.

Comment: @durduvakis you don't have any other htaccess files besides the one in the document root, right? Other than that, I can only think that mod_dir is redirecting.

Comment: hang on! Embarrassed now, my bad, I was testing your code on the wrong firefox tab. Let me check again. Yes I only got an .htaccess in the document root and is a linux ubuntu server not windows

Comment: ok so if I use this url: `/demo/subdirectory1` I get `Not Found` if I use this: `/demo/subdirectory1/` success. Now if I use: `/demo/subdirectory1/subdirectory2` I get the real path exposed plus `Not Found`, and if I use: `/demo/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/` it success again.

Comment: I re-tested with your edited code, I was testing with your first. Your new code returns `Not Found` to all cases. :(

Comment: yes I keep trying your edits, at one point it as almost perfect it was just not redirecting when url was `/demo/subdirectory1` without trailing slash. Right now it just adds about 10 slashes at the end. I keep checking. Thanks alot !

Comment: @durduvakis guess trying to combine the 2 exceptions isn't working, just made it 2 different ones.

Comment: thanks for the help, I was trying different things till now with your code suggestions, the only problem is with the deeper paths like `/demo/subdirectory1/subdirectory2`. The best I came up with so far was by commenting out the first mod_dir part which was causing the many slashes. It worked excellent in all cases even on `/demo/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/` but not `/demo/subdirectory1/subdirectory2` (without trailing slash). It was the only url that was exposing the real path.